# How to make applications save dotfiles at a specified path?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables

Currently, all my config dotfiles and dotfolders (e.g. .cache,.adobe,.compiz) are in my $HOME folder. Is there a environment variable that I can specify which will make all applications save their respective dot files in that folder? e.g.

```
export CONFIG_FOLDER="/home/rajiv/dotfiles"
```

If so, where do I specify this?

Comment: Nothing has changed since over 10 years ago in answers - there is no way to *force* all dot folders and files into a specific subdirectory via env var or otherwise, each program has its own designs around where to store files at the hardcode level so you cant easily change this behavior globally for all applications without rewriting / patching each and every program independently.

Answer (score 7):

**In short, no**.  There is no environment variable that will force applications to save their dotfiles to any path other than `$HOME`.

An alternative, semi-manual approach would be to use [GNU Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/), a symlink farm manager, to move config files for binary packages, as described [in this blog post](http://brandon.invergo.net/news/2012-05-26-using-gnu-stow-to-manage-your-dotfiles.html).

Answer (score 3):

As was posted a decade ago states, the answer is **no**.

Nautilus / Files and other file managers do have an option to hide all files and directories starting with a `.` (dot).

Although this doesn't directly solve your issue, it solves the problem of having the `.names` cluttering up your screen when you are looking for your data files.

By default the `ls` command will not show `.` (hidden) files. You need to use `ls -a` to include "all" for the hidden files to show up.

Answer (score 2):

Most applications have an environment variable you can set to specify where the dotfiles for that app live, but it's not standard.

HOWEVER, if you set the xdg base directories explicitly, I've found probably 70% of apps follow these.  By default is supposed to be ~/.config, but I've found sometimes it only works if explicitly set.

details here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory

tldr: you can make a lot of them behave by just putting 
`export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/.config`
into your .bashrc or.zshrc or equivalent config for your shell.

then reload your terminal/shell session and then move the dotfiles to the new locations.

this won't fix all of them, but it will help with a good chunk.

But nothing has really changed in the 10 years, other than more applications and utilities supporting it.

There is, however, one thing that has changed in ten years: the number of applications that support XDG Base Directories.

You can find the list of supported applications in the table at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory#Supported

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what advantage having your config files in this directory will be. I can only assume you believe it makes it easier for you to view the config files, and modify the settings.

This is one solution, the below script creates a directory if it does not exist called dotfiles, and then creates a symbolic link to each dot file/directory in the dotfiles directory.

create a script file called dotfiles.sh in your /usr/bin directory

```
#!/bin/bash

cd
if [ ! -d dotfiles ] ; then
    mkdir dotfiles
fi
ls -d -w 1 -a -C .[a-z,A-Z,0-9]* | while read -r file; do
    lnfile=${file:1}
    if [ ! -h "dotfiles/$lnfile" ] ; then
        ln -s "$file" "dotfiles/$lnfile"
    fi
done
```

You can setup a cron job, to run at some interval, or add it to apt as a Post Invoke command (DPkg::Post-Invoke), or add it to your bashrc, or even just run it manually when you need it.